# How to deal with different answers that would be a very great answer combined?

Tags: discussion, questions

*Referring to this question: **[Can a range-based for loop take a type argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27502421/2533467)***

This question has three answers that are all correct and good, and would make for a perfect answer if they were combined, because they all focus on different aspects of the question.

One answer explains that it is not possible and why, and the other two answers provide solutions, both applicable depending on the situation and context.

It wouldn't be fair to accept only one of them, because they are all exclusive of each other and would cover every single aspect of the question when combined.

What should I do?

Comment: You know you don't have to accept any answer, right? If one answer doesn't stand out, just don't accept any.

Comment: Yes I know that. And you're probably right.

Comment: Ah, then I don't see the problem? What's the benefit of combining them?

Comment: It would help to tie them together contextually, making it easier to make sense of the problem and its solution. Maybe it's just me, but I like one very thorough answer more than multiple that all just explain a part of what the problem is, and those answers would work perfectly together.

Comment: @gnat objection, I'm asking about combining, none of the answers has to be improved on itself.

Comment: did you check the [top answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255058/839601) over there? "If you want to show exactly how you implemented it and you think that it would be helpful to others then you should probably post a new answer while giving credit to the answer that helped you find your solution..."

Comment: @gnat that is indeed a good answer to my question. I still wouldn't say that my question is a dupe, but it may make sense to declare it as one.

Comment: Usually, when we have multiple correct but fundamentally different answers it's a sign that the question is too broad and should be closed. This doesn't seem to be the case with your question, it's a bit of an edge case. I'm afraid that means that a generalized solution (within the confines of the Q&A format) won't  be easy (or worth it). I also prefer a thorough answer over multiple short ones, but I think there's very little we can - or should - do here.

Comment: We could - for example - combine all the answers in a single wikified one, and delete them. That, however, would mean the answerers wouldn't get any credit for their effort. Hardly an ideal solution.

Comment: After gnats comment, I think a possible solution could also be me answering, citing and linking all three other answers and giving a little bit of additional information on how those answers tie together. I'm not sure how I feel about that, though.