# Falsely ascribing intention on rejected edit

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I posted [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28306695/ruby-csv-not-reading-comma-formatted-numbers-in-quoted-strings), and got a great answer, but there was some additional work to implement it, so I edited the answer for the benefit of future readers. On my edit, I commented `added additional info needed to make the solution work`.

Then I saw that [my edit was rejected](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6936948) by 3 people with the message `This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer.`

While I think they are wrong about `...makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer`, that's a matter on which we can disagree.

My question here is why we have reviewers ascribing intention (`intended to address the author of the post`) where no such intention is expressed nor implied, and the opposite is stated as a comment?

That strikes me as very un-Stackoverflow. I assume (since I have never reviewed an edit) that they are selecting from a predefined list of reasons, and this was the closest to their opinion. Wouldn't it be better to have separate options for `intended to address the author of the post` (to be used when there is evidence of such) and `makes no sense as an edit` (which is fairly subjective).

EDIT: the core of my puzzlement is why `intended to address the author` and `makes no sense` are combined - a reviewer could hold one of those without the other, but they are forced to select both. And how does a reviewer know what the editor's intent was? It's as if the choice was `The editor believes in Santa Claus and the edit contains grammatical errors`? A reviewer who rejects a post for grammatical errors is also making a speculative statement about the editor with no evidence.

I'm not sure how the other answer addresses this. If the reason my edit was rejected is that I shouldn't edit an answer to my own question, then shouldn't the reviewer have an option to select `You are not allowed to edit an answer to your own question.`

Comment: `makes no sense as an edit` is very  broad/vague.  You could use that for literally any edit that merits rejection, and it tells the editor nothing about what they did wrong.  There used to be a reason along those lines, but it was removed because it was just too vague.

Comment: And you are of course correct that this is a canned response, and it's the best of the available options for this particular situation.

Comment: That doesn't seem to match the subject of this question @gnat.

Comment: @Bart per my reading of [rejected edit](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6936948) in question, [top answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255058/839601) in a duplicate explains what asker should actually do instead of attempting an edit

Comment: The OP here seems not to be concerned about the rejection itself, but about the wording of the reasoning @gnat. i.e. why are they ascribing intent, when there is no such intent. Though I'm sure he will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Bart as far as I can tell, the answer over there covers this too: "The rule of thumb is that it is acceptable to edit an answer as long as you don't change the author's intentions..."

Comment: Ideally, answer edits are reviewed by subject experts.  But they don't grow on trees and the reviewers know little or nothing about Ruby.  So they can't judge if your answer edit is technically valid, they prefer that you post a comment instead.

Comment: @Bart got it right - but I guess I didn't explain myself well, because no one else seems to

Answer (score 3):

Part of the problem you have run into has to do with what the reviewer's screen looks like.  If I was reviewing that edit, all I would see is just the diff of the edit you are proposing.  It doesn't show me the question.  It doesn't even necessarily show me the whole answer (just a few lines around your edit so I can get a small bit of context).  Given that, the edit looks like you are telling the author "Hey, this got me really close, but it didn't quite work."  If someone wanted to take the time to click around and read the whole question and answer (and understand enough of the technologies in question), your edit makes sense.  Most people aren't going to do that, especially if they don't know Ruby (in your case).

As far as the rejection reason, as @Servy pointed out in the comments, it is just a canned response.  Rejecting an edit requires specifying why and that is probably the closest reason, given what the reviewer understands at that point.