# Used the idea behind the answer and made a better solution, how to communicate that?

Tags: discussion, attribution

I recently asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28420635/laravel-4-how-to-add-scope-to-dbtable), and got an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28420807/3903565). That answer gave me the idea for what I ended up implementing, which in my mind is a better solution altogether.

Now what? The answer is correct, it does answer my question and solve the problem I had. But I want later users to see what I ended up implementing.

Should I accept the answer and add my solution to the question, add my own answer or try to get the user to answer to expand his answer? As it was the answer I got that gave me the idea I want to give him credit.

Comment: Adding your own answer and giving credit to the other answer would be the cleanest solution. If you want to reward the other answer you could consider giving them a 50 point bounty

Comment: I did exactly the same with one of my questions. It made sense to me.

Comment: @Kendra per my reading, [top answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255058/839601) in a duplicate covers this: "f you want to show _exactly_ how you implemented it and you think that it would be helpful to others then you should probably post a new answer while giving credit to the answer that helped you find your solution..."

Comment: @gnat I thought the consensus was if a _question_ is the same basic question, it should be closed, not if the _answers_ are the same. Or at least, that was how I understood the [Meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/266244/can-a-question-be-a-duplicate-if-its-totally-different) I read on it. As it is, the questions here really are asking two different things. Please do enlighten me if I misunderstand the policy, I'd like to be doing things right after all.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255984/839601

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Stack Overflow is about getting answers to people with problems. It is incentivized by using Imaginary Internet Points™, because as we all know, people will do *anything* for imaginary internet points.

If you think you have a better answer, **by all means post it**. There's no reason to withhold a superior solution simply because you're worried about stealing points from someone else. That said, I'd include a few guidelines.

1. Make sure you **polish your answer**. If you're going to post an answer derived from another user's answer, make sure it's high-quality. If anything, I'd try to make your answer *present the same information in a superior way to the original answer*. Spending a little extra time formatting and arranging your post will easily justify a little duplicate information.
2. **Give credit** where credit is due. Link to the user who originally posted the helpful answer, and link to the answer itself, too. Make it clear what information is yours and what information was derived from the other answer.
3. If you're worried about getting rep from someone else's work, **make your answer community wiki**. This will both invalidate any accusations of rep-hounding and encourage others to improve the answer further, possibly becoming a "definitive" answer.

So yes, do it! I'd also be careful, though. Here are a couple of possible pitfalls to avoid.

1. Make sure your answer **stands on its own**. Your answer should not depend on the existence of the other answer. Anything can happen to the other answer, and if you're trying to make a new answer, *it should be an answer*, not a comment.
2. **Don't sacrifice the clarity of your answer** to provide credit to the original answerer. Provide credit as a courtesy, but don't bend over backwards to do so. Part of the point is to format the information as nicely as possible, even if it doesn't fit into the original author's structure.

Comment: I think this answer lacks one crucial piece of information: Which answer should be accepted, theirs or mine?

Comment: @Lii That's entirely up to you.  Neither is wrong.

Comment: @Servy: But I really don't know and am in need of guidance!

Comment: If I were using information from an answer I would consider it useful, and therefore definitely upvote it.

Comment: @Lii That's like asking us to pick your favorite color for you.  Regardless of how hard the decision is for you, it's still only you that can make it.

Comment: @Lii It is ultimately your choice, but in general I'd *favor* accepting the answer upon which mine is based and which helped me form my answer, because a) even if you think your answer is the best, the acceptance mark is not a "this is the best answer" mark, b) the acceptance mark is (among other things) *the* special way at your disposal to thank someone who helped you. Votes, and everything else you could do, can come from anyone. I'd "favor" means this is not a hard rule: if the other answer sent me in the right direction but my answer fixes a *serious* issue that's a different matter.

Comment: [rep-hounding](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/226737/80130) is preferable and is much less offensive.

Comment: @paqogomez Thank you, I've fixed that.

Comment: I hear that trademark is being infringed. A lot.

Comment: @Lii: Being more logical you should accept the answer which serves best and optimal solution for your question, regardless of your or mine.