# How to deal with an average answer? (if I could give a better one)

Tags: discussion

I've asked a question and received an answer that was helpful and solved my problem. However, now that I understood how to solve it, I think I can devise a better (more clean, concise and with less background needed) answer than the original. How to proceed?

Should I post my own answer? If yes, is it only up to me to decide which one is better to be accepted?

Should I edit the original answer? What if a substantial amount of the answer needs to be edited?

Comment: Related: [I asked a question: Should I accept my own answer or someone else's?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296938/i-asked-a-question-should-i-accept-my-own-answer-or-someone-elses)

Comment: Keep in mind that the person answering doesn't have every single detail which is available to you. Their answer may help in the general case, it is up to you and future readers to modify and tailor the solution to fit the specifics. If the only acceptable answers were those that answered every single localized detail we could never close anything as a dupe.

Answer (score 3):

You can comment on the existing answer, suggesting a change to the answer, if the change is small enough.

If the difference is significant, post an answer of your own.

Comment: And how to decide unbiasedly which one is better?

Comment: You can't. You'll have to judge that on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: What about waiting some days to see which answer gets more upvotes?

Comment: That works, but in the end, you should accept the answer that is, for you, the best answer. That could very well be your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

Just write your own post and mark it as the answer.

Do not forget to give attribution as required by the [site license](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/), you created a "derived work".  Your post *must* include a link to the other user's profile and a link to his post.  Almost always enough to also avoid creating any bad feelings.

Answer (score 1):

Don't modify the Original answer otherwise it going to loose the objective of answerer.

You can add your answer to your question with detailed explanation.

Now after that its your choice to accept whichever you want, or which ever help you to resolve your question.

Then community/other users can upvote any answer whichever help for them individually.

Comment: And how to decide unbiasedly which one is better?

Comment: You don't have to do so...community do this...which answer get more upvote it's better for other users. But at the same time accept that answer which solve you original problems