# Accepting, upvoting and bountying my own answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, bounty, self-answer

Let's say I've asked a question and nobody answered to it or the answers were not fully satisfying. After few days/weeks of searching data I've found out and fixed the problem and I just want to answer to myself, to make other people know the solution and use it in case if they experience same problem as mine.

Is it okay to upvote/accept my own question? Especially when there's a bounty set on it?

Comment: 1. You can't upvote your own answer. 2. You can't bounty your own answer. You can only 1. accept 2. offer bounty to another answer

Comment: If you answer it yourself and mark that one as "accepted", people will see there was a solution that helped the OP (i.e., you again). Other than that, it has to compete with the other answers, as usual - if your solution worked for someone else as well, you might get an upvote.

Comment: It feels like there should be e.g. a minimum upvotes before one could "refund" those lost rep points if there are no better answers.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can't upvote (or bounty) your own answer, you can only accept it. As the OP of the question, you're free to accept *any* answer, including your own. The presence of a bounty does not matter.

Comment: To be complete should probably mention that accepting a self answer doesn't give the reputation bonus or preferential placement on the page.

Comment: It makes perfect sense that you can't upvote your own answer. But why is there a *clickable* upvote button in this case? Why aren't the buttons hidden?

Comment: @noamtm consistency, I guess. Otherwise users would be confusing 'why aren't the vote buttons showing'?